# Adding function to Bootstrap Switch State

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

**Form Field:**

```
<div class="form-group">In-Store Exclusive.
<div class="make-switch pull-right">
<input type="checkbox" id="radstuff" <%if (offer.get('inStoreOnly')) {%>checked<%}%>  disabled>
</div>
</div>
```

**Which outputs as:**

[image]

I am really trying to do something after the 'On or Off' state is toggled. Default is OFF, OK; but I want to hit 'ON' and do something. Say trigger a link opening. I cannot figure out how to access this.

```
coolfunction: function() {
            if offer.get('#radstuff').is('.switch-on');
        {
             window.open("http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?s=100&p[title]=YOUR_TITLE&p[summary]=YOUR_SUMMARY&p[url]=YOUR_URL&p[images[0]=YOUR_IMAGE_TO_SHARE_OBJECT.com",'_blank');
        },
```

Update: Most Recent Attempt.

```
    coolfunction: function ()
      offer.get('#radstuff').parent().is('.switch-on') {
   /*   return true;  */
       alert('Test');
    },
```

After clicking 'OFF' as the above output referenced; NADA.

Comment: Did you looked at http://www.bootstrap-switch.org/#event-handler-javascript ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're using [this widget](http://www.bootstrap-switch.org/), you're not accessing the correct markup to find `.switch-on`.

The markup that is created looks kind of like:

```
<div class='make-switch has-switch' >
   <div class='switch-on switch-animate'>
     <input type='checkbox' checked />
     ....
   </div>
</div>
```

You're code is expecting the `input[checkbox]` element to get the `.switch-on / .switch-off` classes, but it is a div one level higher.  So maybe something like:

```
offer.get('#radstuff').parent().is('.switch-on')
```

Comment: Ah man, this sounded great but no cigar. I updated the question accordingly.

Comment: Winner goes to @Gregg for close as it gets!